Dynamic graphic in GeoServer based on feature property
I am trying to pass my fill parameter for GeoServer SLD and I am using SVG,
found some reference from here GeoServer filter , but getting below error, also sharing the working code where I tried to make rule with and filter
This sample svg can be use here, with any sample data which have two attributes here in my case act_id and structure_type
This one will create dynamic fill value depending upon property value
        <Rule>
          <Name>Cement Nala Bunds</Name>
          <Filter>
            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <PropertyName>act_id</PropertyName>
              <Literal>305</Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource
                   xlink:type="simple" 
                   xlink:href="nrm_styles/KTW.svg?fill=${if_then_else(structure_type == 'existing', '#cfcccc', '#84fa8d')}" />
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>
                <Literal>20</Literal>
              </Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

This one is working which will be forced to make seperate rule for each condintion which will be repeatable
       <Rule>
          <Name>Cement Nala Bunds</Name>
          <Filter>
            <And>
              <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <PropertyName>act_id</PropertyName>
                <Literal>305</Literal>
              </PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <PropertyName>structure_type</PropertyName>
                <Literal>existing</Literal>
              </PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </And>
          </Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="nrm_styles/KTW.svg?fill=#84fa8d" />
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>
                <Literal>20</Literal>
              </Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

Error
java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Invalid cql expression 'if_then_else(structure_type == 'existing', '#cfcccc', '#84fa8d')'
Invalid cql expression 'if_then_else(structure_type == 'existing', '#cfcccc', '#84fa8d')'
Encountered "==" at line 1, column 29.
was expecting one of:
    ")"...
    "."...
    ":"...
    "*"...
    "+"...  
    <IDENTIFIER>...
    "("...
    Parsing : 'if_then_else(structure_type == 'existing', '#cfcccc', '#84fa8d')'

Also trying same thing in CSS module using recode and dynamic url as suggested by previous question
/* @title Cement Nala */
[act_id = 305] {
  mark: url('KTW.svg?fill=#cfcccc');
  mark-mime: "image/svg+xml";
  mark-size: 20;
}

/* @title Cement Nala Bund */
[act_id = 322] {
  mark: url('${if_then_else(structure_type=existing, KTW.svg?fill=#cfcccc, KTW.svg?fill=#ff0000)}');
  mark-mime: "image/svg+xml";
  mark-size: 20;
}


/* @title Cement Nala Bund  */
[act_id = 322] {
  mark-size: 20; 
  :mark {
    url: [
    recode(structure_type,
      'existing','KTW.svg?fill=#ff0000',
      'proposed','KTW.svg?fill=#ff9933'
    )]
  };
  mark-mime: "image/svg+xml";
}


please post the error from the log file as text not an unreadable image

Please click one the image it will open in readable size

Images are unreadable - please paste in the text!

Images are not legible on all devices, and can't be searched by others with the same issue. Text logs should always be posted as text.

please check updated version of question.

I haven't got anything handy to test this on, but I think you just need one '=' instead of '=='.
if_then_else(structure_type = 'existing', '#cfcccc', '#84fa8d')

ECQL Reference: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html

you can see the other example in the format of css style, where i tried this approach which is not working

Did you try it in the SLD? You could also try equalTo(), e.g. if_then_else(equalTo(structure_type,'existing'), '#cfcccc', '#84fa8d'))

as suggested by @SirLostalot tried this approach
<OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="KTW.svg?fill=${if_then_else(equalTo(structure_type,'existing'), '#cfcccc', '#84fa8d'))}" />
but error says
line 23: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'KTW.svg?fill=${if_then_else(equalTo(structure_type,'existing'), '#cfcccc', '#84fa8d'))}' is not a valid value for 'anyURI'. line 23: cvc-attribute.3: The value 'KTW.svg?fill=${if_then_else(equalTo(structure_type,'existing'), '#cfcccc', '#84fa8d'))}' of attribute 'xlink:href' on element 'OnlineResource' is not valid with respect to its type, 'anyURI'

That one might be to do with the '#''s in the colour hex. And my knowledge of this issue is fading fast..... You could try replacing those with something like '#' depending on the encoding, but I'd put that outside of the if_then_else. Perhaps KTW.svg?fill=#${if_then_else(equalTo(structure_type,'existing'),'cfcccc', '84fa8d'))}.
